# org-publish gives multiple entry with quote one of them

Tags: org-mode, org-export

So, I have the following content in the `.dir-locals.el` file for my project:

```
;;; Directory Local Variables
;;; For more information see (info "(emacs) Directory Variables")

((org-mode
  (org-twbs-link-up . "https://psibi.in/prometheus/")
  (org-twbs-link-home . "https://psibi.in/")
  (org-publish-project-alist . '("prometheus" 
                                  :base-directory "~/github/prometheus/"
                                  :recursive t
                                  :base-extension "org"
                                  :auto-sitemap t
                                  :publishing-function org-twbs-publish-to-html
                                  :publishing-directory "~/github/prometheus/docs/"))))
```

Now when I invoke `org-publish` from a file, it gives me two entries:

- quote
- prometheus

Now I don't understand what `quote` is and why it's populated ? What am I doing wrong ? Reproducible repository is here: https://github.com/psibi/prometheus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quoting the value of `org-publish-project-alist`, i.e. you are telling it that the value is

```el
(quote ("prometheus" ...))
```

which causes the confusion you are seeing. You don't want to quote it but you need to fix the structure, since `org-publish-project-alist` is an [alist](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Association-Lists.html#Association-Lists), i.e. a list of dotted pairs:

```el
((org-mode . (
              (org-twbs-link-up . "https://psibi.in/prometheus/")
              (org-twbs-link-home . "https://psibi.in/")
              (org-publish-project-alist . (("prometheus" 
                                             :base-directory "~/github/prometheus/"
                                             :recursive t
                                             :base-extension "org"
                                             :auto-sitemap t
                                             :publishing-function org-twbs-publish-to-html
                                             :publishing-directory "~/github/prometheus/docs/"))))))
```